# Crear 'Beep' con db (decibeles) específicos

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

Buen día, ¿hay alguna extensión o solución para crear un tono Beep con Decibeles, Frecuencia y Tiempo?, en WPF C#

```
Beep(db, frecuencia, duracion);
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Encoontré la manera de hacerlo con NAudio, he aquí el codigo.

```cs
WaveOut sWave = new WaveOut();
SignalGenerator sSignal = new SignalGenerator(sHz, 1); //sHz el nivel de frecuencia en Herz (125, 2000, etc), 1 es el canal

var sEx = new OffsetSampleProvider(sSignal);
sEx.Take = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2); //duración del beep

sWave.Init(sEx);
sWave.Play();
```

Y aquí el desarrollo de [NAudio C#](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)